# Linear map $T^2 = -I$. What does it mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume I have the following linear map:

$$T: \mathbb{R}^n -> \mathbb{R}^n,
\quad\text{s.t.}\quad
T^2 = -I.
$$
How can I prove that $n$ is even?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

$\det(T^2)=\det(-I)$ implies $\det(T)^2=(-1)^n$, hence $n$ must be even.

Comment: could you please explain why did you do it this way?

Comment: @user2953423 this magic is called mathematical maturity